# Is it possible to hold a Boolean value in Pinescript until another condition is triggered?

Tags: indicator

I am trying to create a Pinescript indicator that holds a Boolean value dependent on a condition until another condition is met.

As a very basic example:

buySignal =  high > high[1] and close > open

sellSignal = low  < low[1]  and close < open

if buysignal

```
score := 1
```

if sellsignal

```
score := -1
```

These values are only stored for the single bar that meets these conditions. I would really like to be able to store a +1 or -1 value, until the other signal is triggered.

Is this possible in pinescript?